# How to resolve issue of function not recognized in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a function I am attempting to call in my componentDidMount function. It is function is declared in my mapDispatchToProps function. I am trying to receive variables from the function to display in my render. Instead, I get this error:

TypeError: this.props.pageReload(...).then is not a function

Any advice would help to resolve this issue and hopefully not replicated. I have tried a couple of solutions I ran into but none successful.

Component Level:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Collapse, Container, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarToggler, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { userActions } from '../../../../actions/user.actions';

class InnerHeaderComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
            First: "",
            Last: ""
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {      
        this.props.pageReload()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    First: res.FirstName,
                    Last: res.LastName
                });   
            });                    

    }
 render() {
  return();
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    const { authentication } = state;
    const { user } = authentication;

        return {
        user
    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    pageReload: () => dispatch(userActions.pageReload())
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InnerHeaderComponent);
```

Actions:

```js
function pageReload() {
    return dispatch => {        
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));        
        userService._setUserSession(user);
        dispatch({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user });
        console.log(user);
        return { FirstName: user.FirstName, LastName: user.LastName };
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sandbox?

Comment: I am not sure how to set that up.

Comment: `https://codesandbox.io/s/new`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/74946z17j0

Comment: I have another error on there I am working to resolve.

Comment: @Paradigm A note on your implementation; Redux recommends using the [object form](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops) of `mapDispatchToProps`. It would make your code look like: `const mapDispatchToProp = { pageReload: userActions.pageReload };`. A little easier to read, I think.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will implement and test through out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens normally when you are not returning a promise from your function.  It does't look like your returning a promise from your `pageReload()` function therefore your `.then()` is not valid and you are getting the error. Take a look at [Javascript Promise.protoype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)  Try something like the following:

```
function pageReload() {
    return dispatch => {        
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));        
        userService._setUserSession(user);
        dispatch({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user });
        return Promise.resolve(user)
    };
}
```

and then you can use `then()` like so:

```
this.props.pageReload()
.then(user => {
  console.log(user)
});
```

Note: this is not tested just assuming that's the issue